# Is there a way to create a dataframe from an array of keys and array of values?

Tags: r

Is there a way to create a dataframe from an array of keys and array of values?

How do I create a `data.frame` from the following keys and values?

```
keys = letters[1:5]
values = array(1:50, dim=c(10, 5))
```

Comment: what's your expected output? you should add the desired result to your question so that people will know exactly what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve your rpoblem:

```
df = data.frame(values)
names(df) = keys

    a  b  c  d  e
1   1 11 21 31 41
2   2 12 22 32 42
3   3 13 23 33 43
4   4 14 24 34 44
5   5 15 25 35 45
6   6 16 26 36 46
7   7 17 27 37 47
8   8 18 28 38 48
9   9 19 29 39 49
10 10 20 30 40 50

# Another solution
df = setNames(data.frame(values), keys)
```

Answer (score 0):

I mean, you could actually...

`values <- array(1:50, dim=c(10, 5)) df <- data.frame(keys, values) print(df)`

the `data.frame()` function is used to create a data frame from the `keys` and `values` arrays.

Comment: Thanks, but `keys` ended up as a column...